# Use VBO to send tokenised email in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, views

I have a view table with bulk operations, and I have enabled the send tokenised email field. What I want to do with this is when this is selected and executed, it will take the email of the node which I have selected and send a mail with some content in it to the user. (e.g. we are looking at your support ticket). 
When I select a node in the table currently, select send tokenised email from the dropdown and click execute, it does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Views Send module](http://drupal.org/project/views_send) solved my issue.

> Views Send enables you to send mass mailing from a View.